# Vsftpd: log failed login attempts

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-10.04, fail2ban, vsftpd

I am setting up `fail2ban` in Ubuntu 10.04 for various services. SSH went smoothly, but I have had no success with `vsftpd` so far. The problem is that I can't find a way to get failed login attempts to appear in the logs.

I see nothing in `auth.log` nor in `vsftpd.log`.

[In the example here](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Vsftpd) there are several lines which should appear in the various logs but they don't.

Here is what I have in the config file now:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
session_support=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
```

In the logs I only see successful logins, but when the client gets a `530 permission denied`, nothing is logged.

I would prefer not to log the entire FTP chat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like vsftpd first checks username in `userlist_file` and do PAM only if user is allowed (with above configuration). I would suggest to disable `userlist_*` options and implement deny list in PAM configuration.

```
# put this line into /etc/pam.d/vsftpd as first "auth" check
auth    required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users onerr=fail
```

Then you should see denied log attempts in `auth.log`.

More info - [pam_listfile.so](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-pam-configuration-that-allows-or-deny-login-via-the-sshd-server.html)